# What is the different between pass by reference and pass by value in cpp?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

The compiler said that the method in the class is not found.
Whole error message is 
could not found the function

*common::base::CategoryIdCache::addNewCid(std::string, common::base::eSqlCatalog&, std::vector, std::allocator >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > >&, std::vector, std::allocator >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > >&)*

the candidate is

*common::base::CategoryIdCache::addNewCid(std::string&, common::base::eSqlCatalog&, std::vector, std::allocator >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > >&, std::vector, std::allocator >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > >&)*

Comment: i didn't understand the question ? can you please elaborate a bit ?

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear to me. You're supposed to pass your first argument (string) as a reference (std::string&), rather than as a value (std::string)

Comment: The error message is clearly related (he's passing `std::string`, candidate being `std::string&`) but hard to tell what's wrong without any code.

Comment: @Kippie and how does one pass a reference rather than a value? :)

Comment: @juanchopanza by passing a variable and not a recently-constructed string object. show some code and people can try to help you...

Comment: @Massa I don't need help, thanks. But what you said doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why this could be happening:

- You're either implementing a function with a different signature
- Or you attempt to bind a temporary to a non-const reference

So

```
struct X
{
    void foo(std::string& x);
};

//implementation
void X::foo(std::string x); //wrong - different signature
```

or

```
struct X
{
    void foo(std::string& x);
};

//
int main()
{
    X x;
    x.foo("some string");
}
```

Comment: I have try this way, but there is no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Passing by reference means u're passing the address(reference) of the variable to the function while passing by value means u're copying the value contained at that instant by the concerned variable and then passing it to the function.

You must have declared prototype or the function in a different way as compared to the way you're passing the value.